# Makefile Pattern Rule is found but recipe does not run

Tags: makefile, g++

I have a makefile that has the following pattern rule to create an implicit rule:

```
%.cpp:
    $(warning foo)
```

When I check the output of `make -d` I see that this implicit rule is being found and matching a file. I verify that when I remove the pattern rule, the output of `make -d` no longer shows a match. However, even when the implicit rule is found, the warning doesn't show up. **The recipe isn't running, even though the implicit rule matches**.

What gives?

Comment: What is your actual goal here?

Comment: My goal is to specify a recipe to run for all .cpp files used as prerequisites.

Comment: You want make to run a rule even for `.cpp` files that exist? Then you'll need to convince it to do that even when they are up-to-date. Look at [force targets](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Force-Targets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That recipe tells make how to *create* a `%.cpp` file (and gives it no prerequisites).

When are you expecting it to be run?

It will not run for any existing `*.cpp` files as the lack of prerequisites means that make considers the files up to date.

Try running `make totally-doesnt-exist.cpp` and you should see the warning.

Comment: Yep, you've nicely elucidated where I think I'm going wrong. I've got the dependency idea a bit backwards, I think. I'm trying to specify what to do given a certain target, but really it won't be executed unless the prerequisites are newer (of which there are none!). I should be focusing on the output .o files not on the source .cpp files.

Comment: Right, make operates based on the *output* target not the input files. The inputs are used to select between different matching rules and to create chains of rules, etc.